XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8800/api/proxy due to access control checks
I've been working on accessing an API through an API proxy and got it to work great on a Windows, but when I try it on a Mac environment, it stops working. Currently building for an Excel Plugin.
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8800/api/proxy', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      withCredentials: true
    });
    logMessage(response.data); // Should log "Hello, World!"
  } catch (error) {
    logAxiosError(error);
  }
  
}

Server:
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 8800;

// Load SSL certificates
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};

app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS for all routes

// Middleware to set CORS headers for every response
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Allow all origins, adjust as needed
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); // Allow credentials if necessary
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.sendStatus(200); // Respond to preflight requests
  }
  next();
});

// Simple endpoint that returns "Hello, World!"
app.get('/api/proxy', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server running at https://localhost:${port}`);
});


Don't think I see anything that would cause this (and as can be seen, have also created SSL certificates in case those were the issue).
Here is the image of the errors that I am getting
Tried a server proxy, tried replicating exactly as on the Windows, but ran into above seen error.
